# Scheduled function in Python not starting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made the following script, it connects to a websocket and receives some data from it. While this script is running, i'm trying to run a function every 2 seconds. In this case, the function only prints a message, but of course that's for debugging, it will do other tasks in the future.

My issue is that `Printer()` doesn't start running, i don't see the message appearing every 2 seconds. I know that the problem is that `Connect()` has its own thread, so `Printer()` won't be scheduled until `Connect()` stops working. I want `Printer()` to run **while** i'm receiving data from the websocket. Is there any way to do it? Making it asynchronous? Using more threads?

```
import websocket, json, time, schedule, logging, cfscrape
from websocket import create_connection

try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread


MyList = []
MexCoinsToMonitor = ['XBTUSD']
LastOrder = format(float(time.time()), '.0f')
BU = cfscrape.create_scraper()



def process_message(ws,msg):

    try:
        message = json.loads(msg)
        print(message)


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def Printer():
    print('hello')

def on_error(ws, error):
    print('Error')

def on_close(ws):
    Checker()

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        for value in MexCoinsToMonitor:
            tradeStr=""" {"op": "subscribe", "args": ["orderBookL2_25:%s"]} """%(value)
            ws.send(tradeStr)
            time.sleep(1)
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())

def Checker():
    global LastOrder
    TimeDiff = float(time.time()) - float(LastOrder)
    print (LastOrder, TimeDiff)
    if TimeDiff > 20:
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime", on_message = process_message, on_error = on_error, on_close = on_close)
        ws.on_open = on_open
        ws.run_forever()


def Connect():
    websocket.enableTrace(False)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime", on_message = process_message, on_error = on_error, on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()




Connect()
schedule.every(2).seconds.do(Printer)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(2)
```

To schedule, i'm using the `Schedule` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could indeed make it asynchronious. That would run printer while connect is working. You can use the threading module for this.

```
import threading
threading.Thread(target=Printer).start()
```

That would start a printer. Than you can connect and the printer doesn't have to be finished.

If you want to keep calling the function, just use a while loop.

```
import threading
import time
while True:
    threading.Thread(target=Printer).start()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: I found it hard to wrap my head around what you were trying to achieve. I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! What was hard to wrap around, exactly? Was it because what i'm trying to achieve is difficult or because my question is not clear enough? If it's the latter, i can edit my question :)

Comment: It was hard to get what something should do and when it should do it. Also, I'm not really into websockets, so it probably also is me.

Comment: Ok! Thank you! So i'm trying with threading, the function runs when i start the script, the only problem is that it is not being scheduled, it won't run every 2 seconds. I'm trying to understand why

Comment: Ok! The issue is that it needs to run in parallel to connect, so while connect is working and it sends the data, every 2 seconds i also need to see 'hello' being printed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213019/discussion-between-chris-fowl-and-jack022).